# Xcode debugging: Exception cached?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, caching

I have an issue with cached error handling in X-Code. 
I commented a particular line out, but i still get the same error for this line.

I cleaned the project, i deleted the build folder, i replaced (deleted and imported again) all references. But still i get an error in the line where is nothing. Even if i comment out everything, i get the same error.

```
- (void) setTileSource: (id<RMTileSource>)newTileSource
{
    if (tileSource == newTileSource)
        return;

    RMCachedTileSource *newCachedTileSource = [RMCachedTileSource cachedTileSourceWithSource:newTileSource];

    newCachedTileSource = [newCachedTileSource retain];
    [tileSource release];
    tileSource = newCachedTileSource;
```

**---> here is the SIGABRT exception**

```
     // NSAssert(([tileSource minZoom] - minZoom) <= 1.0, @"Graphics & memory are 
    [projection release];
    projection = [[tileSource projection] retain];

    [mercatorToTileProjection release];
    mercatorToTileProjection = [[tileSource mercatorToTileProjection] retain];

    [imagesOnScreen setTileSource:tileSource];

        [tileLoader reset];
    [tileLoader reload];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that means that the exception is not caused by the line you commented out.

Firstly, why do you do this:

```
newCachedTileSource = [newCachedTileSource retain];
```

`retain` returns self.  You don't need to assign the result to the same object pointer.  If the library overrides retain to return something different, the library is broken.

Secondly, I think this might be a bug:

```
[projection release];
projection = [[tileSource projection] retain];
```

If `projection == [tileSource projection]` before the release, it may be possible it is somehow getting over released.  Does the problem go away if you do:

```
RMProjection* newProjection = [[tileSource projection] retain];
[projection release];
projection = newProjection;
```

Ideally, you would create a synthesized retain property for projection (actually projection could just get the value from the tileSource) like so:

```
-(RMProjection*) projection
{
    return [[self tileSoruce] projection];
}
```

Same for mercatorToTileProjection.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you *retain* the `titleSource`? Try,

```
tileSource = [newCachedTileSource copy];
```

Comment: The line which is commented out logs text and even outcommented it shows that line in the debug area.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`[tileSource release];`

to

    `[tileSource autorelease];`